# Puppet masterport

Tags: puppet, open-source

You can have Puppet listen on a custom port as port 80 instead of 8140 as I have seen it.

It can be set in `etc/puppet/puppet.conf` as

> masterport=80

There is a command, don't know if I use it right `puppet agent --server puppetmaster --masterport 80` to tell the agent to listen on port 80. Yet after changing the conf file on the master and restarting puppet it still listens on port 8140 on the master.

**Reference:**

- [Puppet Configuration](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/configuration.html#masterport)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change needs to be done in these two configuration files:

`/etc/puppet/puppet.conf`

```
[main]
...
user=root
masterport=80
```

`/etc/default/puppet`

```
...
PORT=80
```