# Puppet.conf server specify port?

Tags: puppet

I have a puppet server running inside a docker container with port `8140` being passed to `32779`. Leaving me with a puppet server running on `localhost:32779`.

I then edit my `/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf` and add the following:

```
[agent]
server = localhost:32779
```

Then I run `puppet agent --test` which returns:

> Error: Could not request certificate: Failed to open TCP connection to
>   puppet:8140 (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)

Since I specified port `32779` I'm confused as to why puppet is looking to connect on `8140`?

Is it not possible to specify the port?

*Note: I'm trying to connect to the container from my main system which is running Docker. But when I run* [this docker container](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet-in-docker/blob/master/puppet-agent-ubuntu/Dockerfile) *, which is an agent, it seems to connect. Yet I can't connect directly.*

---

*Edit:*

Running `puppet agent --test --server_list localhost:32779` results in:

```
WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
      hiera (< 4, >= 2.0)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
Warning: Could not select a functional puppet master
Warning: Unable to fetch my node definition, but the agent run will continue:
Warning: Failed to open TCP connection to puppet:0 (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Error: /File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache/facts.d]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': Failed to open TCP connection to puppet:0 (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)
Error: /File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache/facts.d]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet:///pluginfacts: Failed to open TCP connection to puppet:0 (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)
Info: Retrieving plugin
Error: /File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache/lib]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': Failed to open TCP connection to puppet:0 (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)
Error: /File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache/lib]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet:///plugins: Failed to open TCP connection to puppet:0 (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Failed to open TCP connection to puppet:0 (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
Error: Could not send report: Failed to open TCP connection to puppet:0 (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)
```

---

*Edit #2:*

Full output from command `puppet agent --test --server_list localhost:32779 --verbose --debug`:

```
WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
      hiera (< 4, >= 2.0)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
Debug: Applying settings catalog for sections main, agent, ssl
Debug: Caching environment 'production' (ttl = 0 sec)
Debug: Evicting cache entry for environment 'production'
Debug: Caching environment 'production' (ttl = 0 sec)
Debug: Evicting cache entry for environment 'production'
Debug: Caching environment 'production' (ttl = 0 sec)
Debug: Evicting cache entry for environment 'production'
Debug: Caching environment 'production' (ttl = 0 sec)
Debug: Failed to load library 'selinux' for feature 'selinux'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'confdir': 'File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet]{:path=>"/home/philip/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'codedir': 'File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/etc/code]{:path=>"/home/philip/.puppetlabs/etc/code", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'vardir': 'File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache]{:path=>"/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'logdir': 'File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/var/log]{:path=>"/home/philip/.puppetlabs/var/log", :mode=>"750", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'statedir': 'File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache/state]{:path=>"/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache/state", :mode=>"1755", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'rundir': 'File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/var/run]{:path=>"/home/philip/.puppetlabs/var/run", :mode=>"755", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'libdir': 'File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache/lib]{:path=>"/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache/lib", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'preview_outputdir': 'File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache/preview]{:path=>"/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache/preview", :mode=>"750", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'certdir': 'File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet/ssl/certs]{:path=>"/home/philip/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet/ssl/certs", :mode=>"755", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'ssldir': 'File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet/ssl]{:path=>"/home/philip/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet/ssl", :mode=>"771", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'publickeydir': 'File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet/ssl/public_keys]{:path=>"/home/philip/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet/ssl/public_keys", :mode=>"755", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'requestdir': 'File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet/ssl/certificate_requests]{:path=>"/home/philip/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet/ssl/certificate_requests", :mode=>"755", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'privatekeydir': 'File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet/ssl/private_keys]{:path=>"/home/philip/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet/ssl/private_keys", :mode=>"750", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'privatedir': 'File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet/ssl/private]{:path=>"/home/philip/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet/ssl/private", :mode=>"750", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'hostcert': 'File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet/ssl/certs/admin2klic-hp-elitebook-8560p.2klic.pem]{:path=>"/home/philip/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet/ssl/certs/admin2klic-hp-elitebook-8560p.2klic.pem", :mode=>"644", :ensure=>:file, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'hostprivkey': 'File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet/ssl/private_keys/admin2klic-hp-elitebook-8560p.2klic.pem]{:path=>"/home/philip/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet/ssl/private_keys/admin2klic-hp-elitebook-8560p.2klic.pem", :mode=>"640", :ensure=>:file, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'hostpubkey': 'File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet/ssl/public_keys/admin2klic-hp-elitebook-8560p.2klic.pem]{:path=>"/home/philip/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet/ssl/public_keys/admin2klic-hp-elitebook-8560p.2klic.pem", :mode=>"644", :ensure=>:file, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'localcacert': 'File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet/ssl/certs/ca.pem]{:path=>"/home/philip/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet/ssl/certs/ca.pem", :mode=>"644", :ensure=>:file, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'hostcrl': 'File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet/ssl/crl.pem]{:path=>"/home/philip/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet/ssl/crl.pem", :mode=>"644", :ensure=>:file, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'statefile': 'File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache/state/state.yaml]{:path=>"/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache/state/state.yaml", :mode=>"660", :ensure=>:file, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'transactionstorefile': 'File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache/state/transactionstore.yaml]{:path=>"/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache/state/transactionstore.yaml", :mode=>"660", :ensure=>:file, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'clientyamldir': 'File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache/client_yaml]{:path=>"/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache/client_yaml", :mode=>"750", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'client_datadir': 'File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache/client_data]{:path=>"/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache/client_data", :mode=>"750", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'clientbucketdir': 'File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache/clientbucket]{:path=>"/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache/clientbucket", :mode=>"750", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'lastrunfile': 'File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache/state/last_run_summary.yaml]{:path=>"/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache/state/last_run_summary.yaml", :mode=>"644", :ensure=>:file, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'lastrunreport': 'File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache/state/last_run_report.yaml]{:path=>"/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache/state/last_run_report.yaml", :mode=>"640", :ensure=>:file, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'graphdir': 'File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache/state/graphs]{:path=>"/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache/state/graphs", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Using settings: adding file resource 'pluginfactdest': 'File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache/facts.d]{:path=>"/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache/facts.d", :ensure=>:directory, :loglevel=>:debug, :links=>:follow, :backup=>false}'
Debug: Evicting cache entry for environment 'production'
Debug: Caching environment 'production' (ttl = 0 sec)
Debug: Evicting cache entry for environment 'production'
Debug: Caching environment 'production' (ttl = 0 sec)
Debug: Failed to load library 'shadow' for feature 'libshadow'
Debug: Evicting cache entry for environment 'production'
Debug: Caching environment 'production' (ttl = 0 sec)
Debug: Failed to load library 'cfpropertylist' for feature 'cfpropertylist'
Debug: Failed to load library 'shadow' for feature 'libshadow'
Debug: Failed to load library 'cfpropertylist' for feature 'cfpropertylist'
Debug: /File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache/state]: Adding autorequire relationship with File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache]
Debug: /File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache/lib]: Adding autorequire relationship with File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache]
Debug: /File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache/preview]: Adding autorequire relationship with File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache]
Debug: /File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet/ssl/certs]: Adding autorequire relationship with File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet/ssl]
Debug: /File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet/ssl]: Adding autorequire relationship with File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet]
Debug: /File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet/ssl/public_keys]: Adding autorequire relationship with File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet/ssl]
Debug: /File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet/ssl/certificate_requests]: Adding autorequire relationship with File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet/ssl]
Debug: /File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet/ssl/private_keys]: Adding autorequire relationship with File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet/ssl]
Debug: /File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet/ssl/private]: Adding autorequire relationship with File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet/ssl]
Debug: /File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet/ssl/certs/admin2klic-hp-elitebook-8560p.2klic.pem]: Adding autorequire relationship with File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet/ssl/certs]
Debug: /File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet/ssl/private_keys/admin2klic-hp-elitebook-8560p.2klic.pem]: Adding autorequire relationship with File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet/ssl/private_keys]
Debug: /File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet/ssl/public_keys/admin2klic-hp-elitebook-8560p.2klic.pem]: Adding autorequire relationship with File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet/ssl/public_keys]
Debug: /File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet/ssl/certs/ca.pem]: Adding autorequire relationship with File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet/ssl/certs]
Debug: /File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet/ssl/crl.pem]: Adding autorequire relationship with File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/etc/puppet/ssl]
Debug: /File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache/state/state.yaml]: Adding autorequire relationship with File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache/state]
Debug: /File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache/state/transactionstore.yaml]: Adding autorequire relationship with File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache/state]
Debug: /File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache/client_yaml]: Adding autorequire relationship with File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache]
Debug: /File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache/client_data]: Adding autorequire relationship with File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache]
Debug: /File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache/clientbucket]: Adding autorequire relationship with File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache]
Debug: /File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache/state/last_run_summary.yaml]: Adding autorequire relationship with File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache/state]
Debug: /File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache/state/last_run_report.yaml]: Adding autorequire relationship with File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache/state]
Debug: /File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache/state/graphs]: Adding autorequire relationship with File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache/state]
Debug: /File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache/facts.d]: Adding autorequire relationship with File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache]
Debug: Finishing transaction 24399340
Debug: Evicting cache entry for environment 'production'
Debug: Caching environment 'production' (ttl = 0 sec)
Debug: Evicting cache entry for environment 'production'
Debug: Caching environment 'production' (ttl = 0 sec)
Debug: Evicting cache entry for environment 'production'
Debug: Caching environment 'production' (ttl = 0 sec)
Debug: Evicting cache entry for environment 'production'
Debug: Caching environment 'production' (ttl = 0 sec)
Debug: Evicting cache entry for environment 'production'
Debug: Caching environment 'production' (ttl = 0 sec)
Debug: Evicting cache entry for environment 'production'
Debug: Caching environment 'production' (ttl = 0 sec)
Debug: Evicting cache entry for environment 'production'
Debug: Caching environment 'production' (ttl = 0 sec)
Debug: Runtime environment: puppet_version=4.10.0, ruby_version=2.3.1, run_mode=agent, default_encoding=UTF-8
Debug: Using cached certificate for ca
Debug: Using cached certificate for admin2klic-hp-elitebook-8560p.2klic
Debug: Evicting cache entry for environment 'production'
Debug: Caching environment 'production' (ttl = 0 sec)
Debug: Loaded state in 0.00 seconds
Debug: Evicting cache entry for environment 'production'
Debug: Caching environment 'production' (ttl = 0 sec)
Debug: Evicting cache entry for environment 'production'
Debug: Caching environment 'production' (ttl = 0 sec)
Debug: Failed to load library 'msgpack' for feature 'msgpack'
Debug: Puppet::Network::Format[msgpack]: feature msgpack is missing
Debug: node supports formats: pson yaml binary
Debug: Using cached certificate for ca
Debug: Using cached certificate for admin2klic-hp-elitebook-8560p.2klic
Debug: Creating new connection for https://localhost:32779
Debug: Using cached certificate_revocation_list for ca
Debug: Starting connection for https://localhost:32779
Warning: Could not select a functional puppet master
Debug: Failed to load library 'msgpack' for feature 'msgpack'
Debug: Puppet::Network::Format[msgpack]: feature msgpack is missing
Debug: node supports formats: pson yaml binary
Debug: Creating new connection for https://puppet:0
Debug: Starting connection for https://puppet:0
Warning: Unable to fetch my node definition, but the agent run will continue:
Warning: Failed to open TCP connection to puppet:0 (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Debug: Evicting cache entry for environment 'production'
Debug: Caching environment 'production' (ttl = 0 sec)
Debug: Evicting cache entry for environment 'production'
Debug: Caching environment 'production' (ttl = 0 sec)
Debug: Failed to load library 'msgpack' for feature 'msgpack'
Debug: Puppet::Network::Format[msgpack]: feature msgpack is missing
Debug: file_metadata supports formats: pson yaml binary
Debug: Creating new connection for https://puppet:0
Debug: Starting connection for https://puppet:0
Error: /File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache/facts.d]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': Failed to open TCP connection to puppet:0 (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)
Debug: Failed to load library 'msgpack' for feature 'msgpack'
Debug: Puppet::Network::Format[msgpack]: feature msgpack is missing
Debug: file_metadata supports formats: pson yaml binary
Debug: Creating new connection for https://puppet:0
Debug: Starting connection for https://puppet:0
Error: /File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache/facts.d]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet:///pluginfacts: Failed to open TCP connection to puppet:0 (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)
Debug: Finishing transaction 35878660
Info: Retrieving plugin
Debug: Failed to load library 'msgpack' for feature 'msgpack'
Debug: Puppet::Network::Format[msgpack]: feature msgpack is missing
Debug: file_metadata supports formats: pson yaml binary
Debug: Creating new connection for https://puppet:0
Debug: Starting connection for https://puppet:0
Error: /File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache/lib]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': Failed to open TCP connection to puppet:0 (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)
Debug: Failed to load library 'msgpack' for feature 'msgpack'
Debug: Puppet::Network::Format[msgpack]: feature msgpack is missing
Debug: file_metadata supports formats: pson yaml binary
Debug: Creating new connection for https://puppet:0
Debug: Starting connection for https://puppet:0
Error: /File[/home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache/lib]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet:///plugins: Failed to open TCP connection to puppet:0 (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)
Debug: Finishing transaction 36864320
Debug: Evicting cache entry for environment 'production'
Debug: Caching environment 'production' (ttl = 0 sec)
Debug: Loading external facts from /home/philip/.puppetlabs/opt/puppet/cache/facts.d
Debug: Facter: Found no suitable resolves of 1 for ec2_metadata
Debug: Facter: value for ec2_metadata is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for agent_specified_environment is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for lsbrelease is still nil
Debug: Facter: Found no suitable resolves of 1 for ec2_metadata
Debug: Facter: value for ec2_metadata is still nil
Debug: Facter: Found no suitable resolves of 1 for ec2_userdata
Debug: Facter: value for ec2_userdata is still nil
Debug: Facter: Found no suitable resolves of 1 for processor
Debug: Facter: value for processor is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for cfkey is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for ipaddress6_br_2f267500abbb is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for ipaddress6_br_f91b6c0af8c5 is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for ipaddress6_docker0 is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for ipaddress6_enp0s25 is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for ipaddress6_lo is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for macaddress_lo is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for ipaddress_veth9119469 is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for ipaddress6_veth9119469 is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for netmask_veth9119469 is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for ipaddress_veth7239ec2 is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for ipaddress6_veth7239ec2 is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for netmask_veth7239ec2 is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for ipaddress_veth7249d6f is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for ipaddress6_veth7249d6f is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for netmask_veth7249d6f is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for ipaddress_veth738d899 is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for ipaddress6_veth738d899 is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for netmask_veth738d899 is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for ipaddress_vethca47805 is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for ipaddress6_vethca47805 is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for netmask_vethca47805 is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for ipaddress_vethcbb2c83 is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for ipaddress6_vethcbb2c83 is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for netmask_vethcbb2c83 is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for ipaddress_wlo1 is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for ipaddress6_wlo1 is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for netmask_wlo1 is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for sshdsakey is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for sshdsakey is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for sshfp_dsa is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for sshrsakey is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for sshrsakey is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for sshfp_rsa is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for sshecdsakey is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for sshecdsakey is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for sshfp_ecdsa is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for sshed25519key is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for sshed25519key is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for sshfp_ed25519 is still nil
Debug: Facter: Found no suitable resolves of 1 for selinux_enforced
Debug: Facter: value for selinux_enforced is still nil
Debug: Facter: Found no suitable resolves of 1 for selinux_policyversion
Debug: Facter: value for selinux_policyversion is still nil
Debug: Facter: Found no suitable resolves of 1 for selinux_current_mode
Debug: Facter: value for selinux_current_mode is still nil
Debug: Facter: Found no suitable resolves of 1 for selinux_config_mode
Debug: Facter: value for selinux_config_mode is still nil
Debug: Facter: Found no suitable resolves of 1 for selinux_config_policy
Debug: Facter: value for selinux_config_policy is still nil
Debug: Facter: Found no suitable resolves of 2 for swapencrypted
Debug: Facter: value for swapencrypted is still nil
Debug: Facter: Found no suitable resolves of 1 for xendomains
Debug: Facter: value for xendomains is still nil
Debug: Facter: Found no suitable resolves of 1 for gce
Debug: Facter: value for gce is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for network_veth9119469 is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for network_veth7239ec2 is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for network_veth7249d6f is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for network_veth738d899 is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for network_vethca47805 is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for network_vethcbb2c83 is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for network_wlo1 is still nil
Debug: Facter: Found no suitable resolves of 2 for iphostnumber
Debug: Facter: value for iphostnumber is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for vlans is still nil
Debug: Facter: Found no suitable resolves of 1 for zonename
Debug: Facter: value for zonename is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for zpool_version is still nil
Debug: Facter: ruby-augeas not available
Debug: Facter: value for augeasversion is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for is_rsc is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for is_rsc is still nil
Debug: Facter: Found no suitable resolves of 1 for rsc_region
Debug: Facter: value for rsc_region is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for is_rsc is still nil
Debug: Facter: Found no suitable resolves of 1 for rsc_instance_id
Debug: Facter: value for rsc_instance_id is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for lsbminordistrelease is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for zfs_version is still nil
Debug: Facter: Found no suitable resolves of 1 for system32
Debug: Facter: value for system32 is still nil
Debug: Facter: value for ipaddress6 is still nil
Debug: Failed to load library 'msgpack' for feature 'msgpack'
Debug: Puppet::Network::Format[msgpack]: feature msgpack is missing
Debug: catalog supports formats: pson yaml dot binary
Debug: Creating new connection for https://puppet:0
Debug: Starting connection for https://puppet:0
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Failed to open TCP connection to puppet:0 (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
Debug: Creating new connection for https://puppet:0
Debug: Starting connection for https://puppet:0
Error: Could not send report: Failed to open TCP connection to puppet:0 (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)
```

Comment: Somewhat related.  https://serverfault.com/questions/708256/puppet-masterport Not really as much of a dup as I first though.

Comment: What happens if you run `puppet agent --test --server_list localhost:32779`?

Comment: Are you sure it is resolving the hostname? getaddrinfo is a DNS error.

Comment: @ShaneMadden I updated my question with the output from --test --server_list

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride Something's happening before the `Warning: Could not select a functional puppet master` line where it's deciding the master is invalid for some reason (try `curl -k https://localhost:32779` to verify network connectivity through docker) - adding `--verbose` or `--debug` to your command should produce some more details.

Comment: @ShaneMadden I see the port is open with `nmap` but when I use `curl -k https://localhost:32779` I get back a 404. I guess the problem is with my docker container?

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride No, a 404 is good (that's not a valid API path) - so that means the puppet master's reachable, and doesn't explain the "could not select a functional master" error - so, try `puppet agent --test --server_list localhost:32779 --verbose --debug` which will spew a ton of output, look for anything mentioning localhost:32779.

Comment: @ShaneMadden update with full output from `puppet agent --test --server_list localhost:32779 --verbose --debug`

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride I expected something after `Debug: Starting connection for https://localhost:32779` but there's nothing there to tell us why the connection failed. One thing that I didn't expect and may be a hint, is that it's loading a cached certificate (which it shouldn't have if it's never connected to this master) - has this client connected to a different master? Does emptying the `$ssldir` (probably /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl) after backing it up give us different connection behavior?

Comment: Have you tried setting masterport, yet? Works fine for me. `sudo puppet agent -t --server localhost --masterport 32779` attempts correctly and fails (because I have no service listening.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/configuration.html#masterport

> masterport
>
> The port for puppet master traffic. For puppet master, this is the port to listen on; **for puppet agent, this is the port to make requests on.** Both applications use this setting to get the port.

So try setting the master port under your agent section with a value of `32779`.